# Accessing UIScrollView from other ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a viewcontroller, if I press a button, another viewController is loaded, but the first is not unloaded. I want to access a variable form the first view controller from the second, actually a UIScrollView, so that I can use it in this way:

```
scroll1.hidden = YES;
```

How can I do this? I tried importing the .h file, but still I cannot use the UIScrollView

EDIT:

```
NSArray* stack = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
NSInteger currentIndex = [stack indexOfObject:self];
ViewController* linkToA = (ViewController*)[stack objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];

[linkToA.scroll1.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[linkToA.scroll1 addSubview:linkToA.backgroundImage];
```

or

```
ViewController *linkToA = [[ViewController alloc] init];
linkToA = (ViewController*)self.presentingViewController;

[linkToA.scroll1.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[linkToA.scroll1 addSubview:linkToA.backgroundImage];
```

Comment: The best way to do this depends on the structure of your app, and how you are loading the second view controller. Some code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make sure first view controller does have a property of your scrollView in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

if you don't have a latest xcode put `@synthesize scrollView` to the implementation of the first controller

lets say your first controller is A and the second is B

if B is a added as a modal then use this:

```
linkToA = (A*)B.presentingViewController;
```

if B is added to navigationControllerStack:

```
NSArray* stack = [B.navigationController viewControllers];
NSInteger currentIndex = [stack indexOfObject:B];
linkToA = (A*)[stack objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];
```

after you have a linkToA you have to do

```
linkToA.scrollView.hidden = YES;
```

hope this will help

Comment: NSArray* stack = [B.navigationController viewControllers]; has to be included in A or B??

Comment: include this in B (use self instead of B in that case)

Comment: actually with this code it doen't:  NSArray* stack = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    NSInteger currentIndex = [stack indexOfObject:self];
    ViewController* linkToA = (ViewController*)[stack objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];
   
    [linkToA.scroll1.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [linkToA.scroll1 addSubview:linkToA.backgroundImage];  it doesn't give any errors, but the code doesn't do anything

Comment: is `backGroundImage` already a subview of some view in A? is it created?

Comment: Yes, but the code removeFromSuperview which is the most important one is not called either!

Comment: NSArray* subviews = [linkToA. scroll1 subviews];
    for (int i = (int)[subviews count] - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        [[subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: and please make sure that linkToA is not `nil`

Comment: no it doesn't work, but mayby the linkToA is nil, because apart from the code you see in the edit, there is no other code to alloc it, how can i alloc it?? I added this: B *linkToA = [[B alloc] init]; but it still doesn't work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17949/discussion-between-alessandro-and-ezeki)

Comment: em, sorry i don't understand how you create your controllers. If you already have a controller A, then add B as modal like this: `[self presentViewController:[[B alloc] init] animated:YES completion:^{}];` or add B to the navigation stack like this: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[B alloc] init] animated:YES];`. When your B is created, you can use one of the solutions either for modal or for navigation stack case.

Comment: No, the point is that I have a UIStoryboard, and in my storyboard there are two UIViews. then I have two .h files and two .m files. The class of UIviewController A is the first .h, and the second the second .h. Controller B is loaded when in A I press a button for modal segue to the next.

Comment: ah, so it is added as a modal, then use `linkToA = (A*)self.presentingViewController;` inside B to get linkToA